# App not opened programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I installed Meeseva app on my device. When I try to open it programmatically it's not opening.

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Meeseva App://location?id=1"]]) {
    NSString *mystr=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Meeseva App://location?id=1"];
    NSURL *myurl=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:mystr];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myurl];
}
```

When I opened fb, twitter, google+ and etc... all are opening successfully.
Can any solve this this issue?

App link is
https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/meeseva-app/id1121539928?mt=8

Is there any another way to open installed app programatically?

Comment: why do you have a _space_ in the middle of your scheme? (industrial standard here: [RFC-3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.1))

Comment: Because the app name is "Meeseva App" in I tunes...https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/meeseva-app/id1121539928?mt=8

Comment: the _app name_ and the _app's URL scheme_ are __two different__ things; what is your app's URL Scheme? have you defined it explicitly?

Comment: Ok, thank u. How to get that URL scheme. Can u help me to get..

Comment: you need to define your own URL Scheme, here the [Apple's sample app](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/LaunchMe/Introduction/Intro.html) about how to do so.

Comment: @holex No, the OP does not need to define their own URL scheme. The OP is trying to open a 3rd party app. They simply need to know the other app's URL scheme (if it has one).

Answer (score 1):

If your app can receive specially formatted URLs, you should register the corresponding URL schemes with the system. Apps often use custom URL schemes to vend services to other apps.

Hence "Meeseva" app might not have created a custom url for their app. So you can't do anything for it.

As mentioned above the apps which want to provide support for url schema then they have to create a custom URL schemes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out what the correct URL scheme of the Meeseva App is. `Meeseva App://` does not seem to be a valid URL scheme as it has a space in the middle.

For example the Google Maps URL scheme is `comgooglemaps://`, not `Google Maps://`

Usually developers make their URL scheme public in their documentation. However this is a feature that needs to be implemented and apps don't support this "out of the box". If the developer did not implement this, the app can't be opened via link.

Alternatively it is possible that the app reacts on "universal links". That means if there is a website for the app, iOS *might* ask you whether to open that website in the app or in Safari. In that case you could simply link to the website and let the user decide how the link should be opened. However, again, this needs to be implemented by the developer. If the app does not support universal links either, there's no way for you to open the app at all.

Comment: I tried like this MeesevaApp:// , but no use.... How to know the correct URL scheme

Comment: The developer of the app should state this somewhere in their documentation.

Mind: apps do not _have_ to support their own URL schemes or "universal links". That means only apps that do specifically implement this can be opened by URL! But if they do support it, the developer of the app should document this somewhere so it can be used.

Comment: @iOSDeveloper Download the app in question and extract the Info.plist from the ipa file. Look in the Info.plist to see if there are any registered URL schemes.

Comment: With the new iTunes version without App Store the apps are not downloaded to your computer anymore. So it will be difficult to access the .ipa file.